# Angular 5 HttpClient cannot fill variable text

Tags: angular

I have issues with one of my Angylar5 components. I want to execute a get request against an api which receives two GET id's: login and key. The key will get validated and will give a token as response if the key is ok.

- PS, I KNOW THIS IS NOT THE MOST SECURE WAY TO DO AUTHENTICATION *

The console.log(this.authenticationKey) shows undefined. If I put the console.log(res) in the http.get function, the correct response will be logged, why?

The code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DataDevicesService } from '../data-devices.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  authenticationKey: string;
  authenticationToken: string;
  authenticationUrl = 'http://192.168.33.10/fortimanager/v1/api.php?login=authenticate&key=';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  @Input() title: string;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  executeAuthentication() {
    this.http.get(this.authenticationUrl + this.authenticationKey, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(res => {this.authenticationToken = res});
  }

  // changeToken():void {
  //   this.executeAuthentication()
  //     .subscribe(data => this.authenticationToken = data);
  // }

  onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    console.log(f.value);
    this.authenticationKey = f.value["key"];
    // DO SOMETHING WITH THE AUTHENTICATION TOKEN, LOGIC COMES HERE
    console.log(this.authenticationToken);
    $('#authenticateModal').modal('hide');
    //location.reload();
  }
```

Who can help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that http.get returns an observable, this is an async call. So any logic that doesnt wait for the http call to finish may have the result too early. Put your console.log in your subscribe to test.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to know what is Observables:

`Observables` provide support for passing messages between publishers and subscribers in your application. Observables offer significant benefits over other techniques for event handling, asynchronous programming, and handling multiple values.

`Observables` are declarative—that is, you define a function for publishing values, but it is not executed until a consumer subscribes to it. The subscribed consumer then receives notifications until the function completes, or until they unsubscribe.

You need to wait your variable to be defined.

when you call `console.log()` outside `subscribe` your variable is not defined yet

For more informations :[link](https://angular.io/guide/observables)